# Gaming from windows to Ubuntu

Tags: games, streaming

I have thought of building a second PC for running Windows at the same time as Ubuntu for may gaming, I have upgraded parts on my current PC and have the GPU and RAM and the HDD, SDD for the OS, and thought I could build a cheap gaming rig for this purpose. I was wondering if someone has done the same using a Ethernet cable to connect the 2 computers and stream the audio and video from the Windows to Ubuntu for gaming, and send the controller, Keyboard, mouse, and Mic for controlling and gaming. Much like what Valve is talking about with Steam OS and in home streaming.

Windows 7 pro 64 bit - Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Comment: Have you tried using [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-1-0.html) or Wine? Streaming all the control data and video through a Ethernet cable would be fairly complicated, and even then, you probably would not get a decent frame rate...

Comment: Yes and many games work on Wine fine, I just want to know if anyone else has attempted something like this, and streaming would be far easier than configuring Wine, especially with a very large library of games.

Comment: I think he actually wants to stream the games from computer to computer, like on the Nvidia Shield. I don't understand why he wouldn't just get another monitor in that case, stick to the Windows PC for gaming, or dual-boot though.